# What does the "h" in oplog.rs document stand for?

Tags: mongodb

As in here:

```
{
    "ts" : Timestamp(1374832131, 1),
    "h" : NumberLong("-1336944105039123379"),
    "v" : 2,
    "op" : "i",
    "ns" : "users.users",
    "o" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51f24603d98de3716b1db672")
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. **ts**: the time this operation occurred.
2. **h**: a unique ID for this operation. Each operation will have a different value in this field.
3. **op**: the write operation that should be applied to the slave. n indicates a no-op, this is just an informational message.
4. **ns**: the database and collection affected by this operation. Since this is a no-op, this field is left blank.
5. **o**: the actual document representing the op. Since this is a no-op, this field is pretty useless.

Reference: [Replication Internals](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/10/12/replication-internals/)

Comment: here's a [link to a cached version of the above article](http://web.archive.org/web/20131111190520/http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/10/12/replication-internals/)

Comment: This answer is a straight copy from the referenced article, and doesn't make sense without reading the article.

Comment: @GaTechThomas the question is what does "h" means, hence the answer. What did you expect a better answer to be? you cannot reference the article link in the answer becasue that would be closed as low quality answer.

Comment: There is also a new field, called "t", which is the election "term" of the replicaset. For all fields, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/repl/oplog.cpp#L273-L296

Comment: @sfat A better answer wouldn't have given a misleading explanation of the "op" and "o" fields, taken out of context. The OP provided op = i, so the o field is very much not useless.