# What do the oplog fields actually mean?

Tags: mongodb

I've seen this question posed before, but the answers were very vague. I have been doing some research on oplog, and am trying to understand exactly how it works. In particular, I want to have a good understanding of the fields in an oplog document and what data they store.

These are the fields I have found through tests and what I *think* they mean as well as what I am still unsure of:

- ts: timestamp of the write operation / oplog entry
- h: a unique identifier for the oplog entry (but why is it sometimes positive and sometimes negative?)
- op: type of operation performed (usually i/u/d for insert, update or delete)
- ns: database & collection affected
- o: the new state of the document after performing the change
- o2: Seems to contain the _id field of the document during an update operation. Why is this needed when that same field is present as part of the o field, which also contains the rest of the document?
- b: Seems to be a bool that appears for delete operations. What is the significance of this field?

I would like to confirm whether or not the points I made above are accurate, as well as clarifications for the bits that aren't clear. I am also interested to know if there any other fields that can appear in an oplog document.

Comment: Mostly a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878835/what-does-the-h-in-oplog-rs-document-stand-for but that b field: no one seems to really know what it is and it doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: The SO link has correct, AFAIK, descriptions. It's intentional that the format of the oplog is undocumented because it's meant as an implementation detail and MongoDB wants to reserve the ability to adjust or totally change the oplog mechanism. Documenting it creates expectations, intentionally or not.

Comment: what about `v`? v seems important -> the version of the document? gets incremented for every update?

Answer (score 9):

- h is a hash (signed Long)
- ts is the internal timestamp format (the "\x11" type shown at bsonspec.org; search the API docs for your driver at api.mongodb.org for further information)
- you are correct on op, ns, o, and o2
- there's also a "v" field (I'm gonna speculate that this is version, which would allow them to update the schema for the oplog).
- b is True for all the delete operations I could find, so I can't provide any information.

The best source of documentation I've found is [this](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/building-real-time-systems-mongodb-using-oplog-stripe). It was a presentation by a company called Stripe at 2014's MongoDB World conference, and it includes some sample Ruby code.

Comment: "b" has been removed, but the comments say: if not null, specifies a boolean to pass along to the other side as b: param. used for "justOne" or "upsert" flags on 'd', 'u'. See: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/c456786eb2e812440fa6854e2f730b161e6e70ea/src/mongo/db/repl/oplog.cpp#L218-L220

Comment: There is also a new field, called "t", which is the election "term" of the replicaset. For all fields, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/repl/oplog.cpp#L273-L296

Comment: what about v? v seems important -> the version of the document? gets incremented for every update?